# How to get a batch file to read a command from a text file and execute?

Tags: batch-file

How can I get a batch file to read a command from a text file, and then execute the command it has just read?

Comment: what is inside the second file? Just 1 line with 1 command name?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using 2 batch files.

Just put your command(or commands) inside the second batch file

and use batch file `Call` function to execute it.

So `a.bat` conatins:

```
Call b.bat
```

and `b.bat` contains the command, for example

```
Del abc.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (text.txt) do "%%~a"
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that wants to know who is reading this, If you structure an xml file as the file with the values in it, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <CustomValue1>
        My Text I Want
    </CustomValue1>
    <CustomValue2>
        My Text I Don't Want
    </CustomValue2>
</xml>
```

The get the batch file to read that value and put it in a viable to later use:

```
@ECHO OFF

Set "xmlFile=FileName.xml"

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%n in ('findstr /n /i /c:"<CustomValue1>" "%xmlFile%"') do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%l in ('type "%xmlFile%" ^| more +%%n') do call set "Value=%%l" & goto endLoop ) 
:endLoop

ECHO My Value is "%Value%" which I can now construct in to what I want with it
```

What this is doing is it is getting only the value you want, ignoring the other values and then once it's in a variable you can use that how you require, either as a parameters for another .exe or anything else you would like.

Comment: although that might be true - how is it related to the question?

Comment: The Question is "How can I get a batch file to read a command from a text file, and then execute the command it has just read?". 

This gets a value from a file of text that a command can be made from, which the value could also be the command

Comment: a txt file by definition is plain text without any format information. To me, xml doesn't qualify, but ymmv...